# Error in nextjs app using nodemon, don't know how to fix it

Tags: node.js, next.js, terminal, syntax-error, nodemon

i'm following a tutorial to build an ecommerce web app, i'm using next js with typescript, the issues came when in the tutorial he started using nodemon and adding some files for its configuration. Here i post the **nodemon.json** present in the root of the project:

```
{
  "watch": ["server.ts", "src/collections/**/*.ts", "src/trpc/index.ts"],
  "exec": "ts-node --project tsconfig.server.json src/server.ts -- -I",
  "ext": "js ts",
  "stdin": false
}
```

Here is my hand-modified **package.json**

```
...
 "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "cross-env PAYLOAD_CONFIG_PATH=src/payload.config.ts nodemon",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
...
```

and that's the error i get in the terminal when i run npm run dev:

```
[nodemon] starting `ts-node --project tsconfig.server.json src/server.ts -- -I`
"ts-node" non è riconosciuto come comando interno o esterno,
 un programma eseguibile o un file batch.
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

And then here i post the other files used for nodemon configuration:

**tsconfig.server.json**

```
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "CommonJS",
    "outDir": "dist",
    "noEmit": false,
    "jsx": "react"
  },
  "include": ["src/server.ts", "src/payload.config.ts"]
}
```

**src/payload.config.ts**

```
import { buildConfig } from "payload/config";
import { webpackBundler } from "@payloadcms/bundler-webpack";
import { mongooseAdapter } from "@payloadcms/db-mongodb";
import { slateEditor } from "@payloadcms/richtext-slate";
import path from "path";
import dotenv from "dotenv";
/* import { Users } from "./collections/Users";
import { Products } from "./collections/Products/Products";
import { Media } from "./collections/Media";
import { ProductFiles } from "./collections/ProductFile";
import { Orders } from "./collections/Orders"; */

dotenv.config({
  path: path.resolve(__dirname, "../.env"),
});

export default buildConfig({
  serverURL: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_SERVER_URL || "",
  collections: [/* Users, Products, Media, ProductFiles, Orders */],
  routes: {
    admin: "/sell",
  },
  admin: {
    user: "users",
    bundler: webpackBundler(),
    meta: {
      titleSuffix: "- DigitalHippo",
      favicon: "/favicon.ico",
      ogImage: "/thumbnail.jpg",
    },
  },
  rateLimit: {
    max: 2000,
  },
  editor: slateEditor({}),
  db: mongooseAdapter({
    url: process.env.MONGODB_URL!,
  }),
  typescript: {
    outputFile: path.resolve(__dirname, "payload-types.ts"),
  },
});
```

With my self i guess nodemon devs has update the config setting or there maybe be a syntax error, waiting on your advices.

Comment: You are using payload cms right?

Comment: yes i am, the tutorial i wrote about can be found on youtube

Comment: Is it e-commerce website from js mastery?

Comment: no, the title is:  Build a Complete Digital Marketplace with Next.js 14, React, tRPC, Tailwind | Full Course 2023 and it's from the author: Josh tried coding

Comment: I thought i can eventually don't use nodemon, in the end it could be possible to avoid its usage without changing the app functionalities.

Comment: I am also having problem creating a new project with the same error.

Comment: maybe it could be a syntax update, even reinstalling node modules it's the same

Comment: I really don't know I am trying to solve this issue since yesterday but have no success